# How do I select the client only framework in a Managed Visual C++ project in VS 2008 Sp1?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-client-profile

The title said it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible, even with VS 2008 sp1.  You set the target framework under the "Common Properties"->"Framework and References" in the project property pages.  In 2008sp1, the only choices are:

- .NET Framework 2.0
- .NET Framework 3.0
- .NET Framework 3.5